# What is the benefit of the MonadCatch?

Tags: haskell

When I am writing some function which can fail:

```hs
somefun :: (Monad m, ...) -> ... -> m a
somefun ... =
  ...
  fail "some error"
```

I can use `fail` to fail. But also I can rewrite this function to use `MonadThrow`, so:

```hs
somefun :: (MonadThrow m, ...) -> ... -> m a
somefun ... =
  ...
  throwM "Some error"
```

So, today we got `MonadFail`, also we had `Monad` with `fail`, from another point of view, I can fail with `throwM`. What is the right way to write such functions in LTS-11.7? What is the benefit of `throwM` vs. `fail` (because there are libraries with one method and another ones - with other method)?

EDIT:
Also when I saw [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fail.html) I can not understand - it's something temporary, workaround, but in future versions `fail` will be totally removed from `Monad`?

Comment: Not all `Monad`s implement `fail`. For example `Sum`, for example for `instance Monad Sum`.

Comment: Yes, it's true, but what about `MonadThrow`? Is it implemented for all monads?

Comment: no, the entire idea about defining a separate class is that you can implement `Monad` without having to implement `fail`, and furthermore if you for example would use `throwM`, etc. then normally there should be a sensical implementation for `throwM`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem excuse me, what does it mean "sensical"? Existing? Such instance should always exists, for all monads? PS. I am not sure in the meaning of the word, pardon please

Comment: `fail` defaults to `undefined` if I recall correctly, so currently a lot of `fail`s are just `undefined`. It is however a bit non-sensical. Usually one expects `fail` to return a valid `Monad` instance (like `Nothing`, `[]`, etc.).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem so if it's true, better is to use `MonadThrow`'s `throwM`, which as not `undefined` in all existing instances. Is it true always, for all cases?

Comment: `fail`, if memory serves, was mainly intended to handle pattern-match failures in `do`  notation, rather than something you explicitly call.

Comment: instead of `zero`/`MonadZero` ? But today it's using in many places...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to fail, but in the end all failures are translated into three categories:

- Pure failure handling, something like a `Maybe` or `Either` monads. This is the best way to handle failure, but it is not always possible
- Exceptions. These can be thrown from pure code, but you really should always avoid doing that. Therefore if you need to handle exceptions, stay in something like an `IO` monad.
- Asynchronous exceptions. These can pop at any time. They should never be recovered from and in general should be used in extremely rare case.

Here are some of the ways to fail, that should really be avoided:

- `undefined` - when evaluated is translated into runtime exception. The worst way to fail and is only justified as an argument to some existing functions where it won't be evaluated, eg. `sizeOf`, `alignment`, etc. These sort of functions should be written with `Proxy` instead, but that is orthogonal.
- `error` - also translates into runtime exception. Should be used only in impossible cases that can never happen.
- `throw` - same as `error`, but allows throwing specific exceptions. Should also be avoided, cause due to laziness it might get evaluated in places where you  least expect it.
- `fail` - for most monads implementation is to throw an `error` (default implementation). As pointed out by @chepner, it was designed for pattern match failure and shouldn't really be used. Nevertheless it is still popular, especially in parsing.

All of the above should be avoided, since their usage results in runtime exceptions from pure code.

Proper way to fail:

- `Maybe`, `Either`, `Validation`, etc. fail purely without exceptions.
- `throwIO` - proper way to throw exceptions, when in `MonadIO`
- `throwSTM` - correct way to throw exceptions if you are in `STM`.
- `throwM` - has a appropriate failure implementation that depends on a concrete `Monad`. In other words it defers the decision on how to fail to the user of the function, which can be pure or not, depending on the monad.

With the preface over let's get to the actual question.

Here is a good example of why `fail` is bad, before the MonadFail Proposal was implemented:

```hs
λ> let unsafeDiv x y = if y == 0 then fail "Division by zero" else pure (x `div` y)
λ> 5 `unsafeDiv` 0 :: Maybe Int
Nothing
λ> 5 `unsafeDiv` 0 :: Either String Int
*** Exception: Division by zero
λ> 5 `unsafeDiv` 0 :: IO Int
*** Exception: user error (Division by zero)
```

`STM` is another example where `fail` is really bad, since it results in a call to default implementation: `errorWithoutStackTrace :: [Char] -> a`. (see [`throwSTM`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-07-17/stm-2.5.0.0/Control-Monad-STM.html#v:throwSTM) on why it's bad)

So with `fail` we will get not only different exceptions, but also incorrect behavior.

On the other hand we have `MonadThrow`:

```hs
λ> let safeDiv x y = if y == 0 then throwM DivideByZero else pure (x `div` y)
λ> 5 `safeDiv` 0 :: Maybe Int
Nothing
λ> 5 `safeDiv` 0 :: Either SomeException Int
Left divide by zero
λ> 5 `safeDiv` 0 :: IO Int
*** Exception: divide by zero
```

We will always get the same exception that was thrown, granted that the monad supports its propagation. As a consequence of that we can always catch the exception that was thrown. It guarantees ordering, so the exception will not escape due to laziness.

The most correct answer to your question, I think, is to use the failure method that is specific to the monad you are in, but if you don't know the exact monad ahead of time, and want to let the user of your function to choose how to fail, go for `throwM`

On a related topic I would advise against using `MonadCatch` and instead use something like [`unliftio`](https://www.stackage.org/package/unliftio) or [`safe-exceptions`](https://www.stackage.org/package/safe-exceptions). See more info about exception handling [here](https://haskell.fpcomplete.com/tutorial/exceptions).

Comment: Man, what if we changed `STM`'s instance so [`fail _ = retry`](https://github.com/dmwit/mcmario/blob/wip/macerole/src/MCMario/STM.hs#L44)? Wouldn't that be rad? Then you could write `pat <- act` to make an action which blocked until its computation produced something that matched the pattern `pat`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, interesting idea, but feels a bit like an abuse of `fail`. Although it is a common pattern to retry when some action returns something like `Nothing`. Despite that I would still go with a more explicit `case` statement on that. When dealing with concurrency it is better to be clear about what you are doing rather than being cool :) It is still a cool idea though.

Comment: Using an explicit `case` adds two levels of indentation each time (one for the patterns, one for the new `do` block), and requires at least twice as many patterns. If you had two or three such checks in a row that would become quite cumbersome indeed. See e.g. [here](https://github.com/dmwit/mcmario/blob/wip/macerole/src/mcmario.hs#L136-L140) for an example where it is quite natural to have two such checks in a row -- requiring four additional levels of indentation and two extra fallback actions would make this much more difficult to understand, I think!

Comment: It is certainly get's more verbose, but in my opinion gets clearer of what exactly is going on. https://gist.github.com/lehins/3653b53a6ace028bf0158c53294145f3 Deadlocks are not easy to debug as it is. Indentation is rarely a problem, unless you use tabs ;)

Answer (score 1):

`fail` is a *handler* for pattern-match failures in do-notation, not something that *signals* an error for other functions to handle.

From the documentation for `MonadFail`:

> When a value is bound in do-notation, the pattern on the left hand side of <- might not match. In this case, this class provides a function to recover.